# Show all fields from bibtex in references

Tags: bibtex

I made a bibliography using JabRef and in the references in my latex document only author and title show up, but not the URL or the URL date. My latex file looks like this:

```
\begin{document}

\cite{weiss}

\bibliography{Bibliography} 

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

and my .bib file looks like this:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Online{weiss,

  author  = {Dieter Weiß},

  title   = {Lumineszenz},

  url     = {http://www.chemie.uni-jena.de/institute/oc/weiss/lumineszenz.htm},

  urldate = {2019-01-23},

}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

In my references I get:

> [1] Dieter Weiß. Lumineszenz.

I would like the URL and the URL date to show up too, and just generally now how I can change which fields are shown and which are not. I know this is decided by the bibliographystyle, but none of the styles I tried show it. I googled for literally hours and couldn't find any precise information on this, so I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: The short answer is that `.bst` bibliography styles only print the fields they have been set up to use and know. `plain` is one of the oldest `.bst` styles and does not know `url` and `urldate`. It is possible to modify a `.bst` file to print fields it does not know, but the language of `.bst` files might be a bit hard to stomach at first, so I would recommend to find a style that does the right thing out of the box. ...

Comment: ... `urldate` in particular is not supported by a lot (any?) BibTeX styles. It is a field usually associated with `biblatex`. So it might well be worth thinking about a switching from BibTeX to `biblatex` (notice the **`la`**), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864. Your JabRef seems to be in `biblatex` (and not BibTeX) mode already.